# Find all combinations of two vectors as a new vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
x <- c('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3')

y <- c('Yes', 'No')
```

Based on these vectors I would like to create a data frame where each row would be a vector where questions (Q1, Q2, Q3) are on odd positions in order they are in vector x, and the answers (Yes, No) are on even positions and I need all possible combinations:

```
'Q1', 'Yes', 'Q2', 'Yes', 'Q3', 'Yes'
'Q1', 'Yes', 'Q2', 'Yes', 'Q3', 'No'
'Q1', 'Yes', 'Q2', 'No', 'Q3',  'Yes'
```

and so on...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be

```
expand.grid(combn(x, 2, FUN = list), y)
```

The above creates a `list` column along with a normal column.  If we need a `matrix`

```
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, c(f = c, expand.grid(combn(x, 2, 
           FUN = list), y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a matrix with 3 columns, and I need a matrix with 6 columns.Something like this maybe: Q1 Yes/No Q2 Yes/No Q3 Yes/No

Comment: The output you showed in the expected is not a R structure

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
ans <- expand.grid(rep(list(c("Yes", "No")), 3))
qst <- as.data.frame(sapply(x, function(i) rep(i, nrow(ans))))

ret <- cbind(qst, ans)
ret[as.numeric(sapply(1:length(x), function(i) c(i, i + length(x))))]
#  Q1 Var1 Q2 Var2 Q3 Var3
#1 Q1  Yes Q2  Yes Q3  Yes
#2 Q1   No Q2  Yes Q3  Yes
#3 Q1  Yes Q2   No Q3  Yes
#4 Q1   No Q2   No Q3  Yes
#5 Q1  Yes Q2  Yes Q3   No
#6 Q1   No Q2  Yes Q3   No
#7 Q1  Yes Q2   No Q3   No
#8 Q1   No Q2   No Q3   No
```

The last two lines do the following:

1. Column-bind the questions and answers.
2. Re-arrange the columns such that questions and answers are alternating. `as.numeric(sapply(1:length(x), function(i) c(i, i + length(x))))` returns `1 4 2 5 3 6`, which gives the vector of indices for the columns to be ordered.

Comment: The code works just fine, but I don't quite understand the last line, can you please clarify it a bit for me?

Comment: @hoze I've added some explanations about the last two steps. Please take a look.